# can't modify output from scanner unreadable

Tags: java, eclipse, io, java.util.scanner

Having a problem to get readable output from the scanner output. Tried without IO, and output in console is also unreadable. There is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;

class dane {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = null;
        Set<String> dane = new TreeSet<String>();

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dane.txt")));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String Ala1 = s.next().split(" ").toString();
                dane.add(Ala1);
                System.out.println(dane);
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output from `TreeSet` is:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@14eac69, 
[Ljava.lang.String;@1909752, 
[Ljava.lang.String;@1f96302]
```

I tried to add `.toString()` method, but it didn't help.
My txt file is very easy,contains just three words, which I then wanted to split to letters and print out in alphabetical order. But with such output I can't proceed.

Comment: I formatted your question but in the future please do it yourself. Any IDE has this functionality.

Comment: `next()` already uses ` ` as a delimiter , so `String Ala1 = s.next().split(" ").toString();` calling `split()` and also `toString()` are redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Split` method returns array of elements, so you need to choose first element of array to put to `Set`

```
String Ala1 = s.next();
```

Comment: I got your idea, thanks! I modified my code the following way  that I added 3 different strings

Comment: `split(" ")[0]` after `next()` doesn't make any sense if we are using Scanner and we don't change its delimiters because by default Scanner is using any whitespace as delimiter which means that `next()` can return only single tokens between delimiters (words). So `split(" ")` will simply wrap this word in array and `[0]` will return same element from that array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner s = null;
    Set<String> dane = new TreeSet<String>();

    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dane.txt")));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String Ala1 = s.next().split(" ")[0];
            dane.add(Ala1);
            System.out.println(Ala1);
        }
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

You were printing the set instead of string in the loop. The .toString() is redundant.